# What is the number behind the HTTP response status code?

Tags: http, flask, heroku, http-status-code-404, response

I encountered "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 25 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" and "POST /tvwebhook HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" in Heroku logs after a POST request is accepted on my flask app before in which the latter would make my Heroku deployed flask app not function as it should. However I have no idea what is 25 and 31 meaning

Comment: I wrote an answer for Heroku router logs, but it doesn't look like that's what you're showing here. Can you provide complete log lines and more context? Which WSGI server are you using (e.g. Gunicorn, Waitress, uWSGI, ...)? This might be coming from there.

Comment: It's _probably_ the number of bytes transferred, but without more context we can't say for sure.

Comment: @Chris I am using Gunicorn Flask app run in Heroku Cloud. The complete log lines are 2022-08-23T16:01:04.058298+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.87.192 - - [23/Aug/2022:16:01:04 +0000] "POST /tvwebhook HTTP/1.1" 200 25 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1". This happens probably because my flask app server returns a JSON response object differently with make_response status code of 400 for the "31" and 201 for "25". Not sure why it is so

Answer (score 0):

I believe those lines are coming from Gunicorn, via [Heroku's Logplex router](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logplex).

Logplex provides everything up to the dyno information, e.g.

```
2022-08-23T16:01:04.058298+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

And Gunicorn provides the rest, e.g.

```
10.1.87.192 - - [23/Aug/2022:16:01:04 +0000] "POST /tvwebhook HTTP/1.1" 200 25 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
```

Gunicorn's [default access log format](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#access-log-format) suggests that this is the length of the HTTP response in bytes (the amount of information your app sent to the client as a response to this request):

> | Identifier | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | h | remote address |
> | l | `'-'` |
> | u | user name |
> | t | date of the request |
> | r | status line (e.g. `GET / HTTP/1.1`) |
> | m | request method |
> | U | URL path without query string |
> | q | query string |
> | H | protocol |
> | s | status |
> | B | response length |
> | b | response length or `'-'` (CLF format) |
> | f | referer |
> | a | user agent |
> | T | request time in seconds |
> | M | request time in milliseconds |
> | D | request time in microseconds |
> | L | request time in decimal seconds |
> | p | process ID |
> | {header}i | request header |
> | {header}o | response header |
> | {variable}e | environment variable |